# posts stuck as drafts

Tags: theme-development, post-status

I've recently seen a new bug appear on a site running WP e-commerce. New products (or certain existing products) get stuck as 'drafts'. Once they are marked as draft clicking 'publish' does not do any good, and the only way to make the products publicly accessible is by directly editing the entry in the MySQL database.

**UPDATED**
Further investigation shows that this is not an wp-ecommerce problem - it affects all posts.

Switching to twentyten theme fixes the problem, so clearly the inability to publish must lie somewhere in the custom theme I'm using. Seeing as it's my own theme, I guess I'm to blame ;-)

Error reporting throws up a mention of an incorrectly called register_script() function, however I don't think this is what's causing the problem, as it's not in my code.

Comment: Difficult to isolate problem. Its likely that (if not a setting within wp-ecommerce) that another plugin or recently added (?) piece of code may be interfering with the `save_post` function, somehow overwriting the publish status with draft regardless of user intent. What have you done to try and solve this thus far? Try disabling all plugins and re-testing, then enabling one plugin **one-by-one** to rule out plugin conflicts and whether the issue lay with the wp-ecommerce plugin itself.

Comment: Hi @userabuser. Disabling all plugins apart from wp-ecommerce itself had no effect unfortunately. I'm not seeing any php errors either, so I'm a bit flummoxed as to where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have some custom functions in your themes functions.php Add a `return;` on top of this file. If the problem is solved: Move it below the first function. Proceed this way until you've found the function that is causing the problem.

If this doesn't work: Go and do the same for one template file after each other until you found the file that is causing the issue.

Comment: Ohh - nice idea. I'll try that.

Comment: This was the best procedure, and allowed me to identify the bug - which was introduced by a bit of jQuery that broke the 'publish' button.

Comment: @fred2 Bounty welcome :)

Comment: @kaiser Add a `return;` after the bounty, to me. Good suggestion ;)

Comment: @fred2 Completely overlooked that: Please award the Bounty to "userabuser" as he's done the major work on this topic. Hint: Your bounty rep points are already gone and won't come back no matter if you award them or not.

Comment: I would share them between you if I could :-( I have to wait a few more hours before assigning the reward...

Comment: @fred2 Nah, just give it to "userabuser" - We need more high rep people to keep the system clean, and he is helping alot on here. :)

Comment: Thanks to you both - much appreciated ... @userabuser rewarded.

Comment: @kaiser Noo! I was joking around mate that was not necessary - sorry if caused confusion.

Answer (score 4):

In that case your error lays with **wp-ecommerce** itself as you've ruled out any via process of elimination.

The last thing I would suggest you do, is switch from your current theme to the default WordPress theme (**still ensuring that all plugins except wp-ecommerce are disabled**) and if the problem still persists then its definitely wp-ecommerce.

We can assume this even more so because the default theme (if never altered before) will provide the best test conditions for this scenario.

> i.e. no functions.php alternations etc have been made by the user
>   that could possibly interfere with the plugin in question and since no
>   other plugins are installed whilst running this test then we know who
>   the problem is).

After that, if the problem persists you need to seek help from wp-ecommerce or hire a WP professional to take a look at it for you because it sounds like physical look-and-see access is going to be needed to troubleshoot this one properly unless you can provide any further information to debug.

You can try putting your WP installation into debug mode by editing your wp-config.php file and setting `WP_DEBUG` to `true` and see if any error notices are being thrown that indicate as to what the cause may be.

What is your current version of WordPress installed?

Comment: Thanks again. Wordpress is 3.4.2. See my updates to the question above. It does seem to be connected to my own custom theme. WP_DEBUG does not seem to indicate an obvious error in the code. I'm able to debug the code myself - main reason for posting was to see if anybody had an idea where to look in the absence of any php error reports.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you have accidentally changed your user role from Editor to Contributor -- perhaps in your functions.php file (which is why it might only happen on your custom theme)?

Contributors roles can only save draft for new posts and can't publish.  You might like to check that your didn't change anything in your custom theme so that if user can't manage options (for example), then they can't save / publish a posts.

Comment: I'm logged in as superadmin, but it could be that some permissions have been disrupted...